# Can't See All Option In Dropdown Because Of Pagination

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I did pagination for my invoice as well as vendor table. i have a create invoice form in which i have dropdown option for selecting vendors, i have more than 20 vendors, after doing pagination i see in my form i have only 10 vendors in my dropdown option... I don't know how to fix this issue.

Did Pagination Like this:

**In HTML**

```html
<!--PAGINATION FOR VENDORS TABLE -->
<pagination :data="ticketInvoices" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>

<!--PAGINATION FOR VENDORS TABLE -->
<pagination :data="vendors" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
```

**`methods:{}` of both pagination**

```js
//METHOD FOR INVOICE
getResults(page = 1) {
  axios.get("api/ticket-invoice?page=" + page).then(response => {
    this.ticketInvoices = response.data;
  });
},

//METHOD FOR VENDOR
getResults(page = 1) {
  axios.get("api/vendor?page=" + page).then(response => {
    this.vendors = response.data;
  });
},
```

**`InvoiceController` & `VendorController`**

```js
/*Invoice Controller*/
class TicketInvoiceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $ticketInvoices = TicketInvoice::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return $ticketInvoices;
    }

/*Invoice Controller*/
class VendorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $vendor = Vendor::paginate(10);
        return $vendor;
    }
```

**Before Pagination**
[image]

**After Pagination**
[image]

Comment: You'll need to determine when to load the next page of your pagination. It's not automatic.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if you don't mind can you guide me with some code ?

Comment: What if the number of vendors becomes hundreds and thousands? There's a similar question today here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330040/how-to-optimize-the-load-of-many-data-options-into-a-select-box-from-db-passed-v/53330915?noredirect=1#comment93544604_53330915  Better to use a "search and select" interface or an autocompletion field?

Comment: @hktang Yes i have to go with autocomplete.... Lets try.

Comment: @hktang The example u showed me i do somthing like that but, i'm confused, i'm also using vuejs, axios etc, can u help me with some code if u don't mind ?

Comment: @SaifZakir Hi, Saif I am not familiar with VueJS, but this link might help: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/

Comment: @hktang Thanks for your support, i hope this will help me out. :)