# How to optimize the load of many data options into a select box from db passed via a variable in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm populating a `select box` with data from a database. The thing is that there are **139659** elements inside it (just getting from a single column).

I tried it once and I guess *all* the data got loaded, and of course my application got slow loading all that stuff.

So, *how could I optimize the data fetch from it?* I will use `select2` to get more functionalities, though I think I first need to address how to load the data.

My code:

```
<div id="inputs-postal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="codigoPostal" id="select-cp">
            @foreach ($cpostales as $cp)
                <option value="{{ $cp->postal_code }}">{{ $cp->postal_code }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{

// Toma los estados de la base de datos.

$estados = DB::connection('db_postalcodes')
    ->table('state')
    ->groupBy('state')
    ->get();
$cpostales = DB::connection('db_postalcodes')
    ->table('postal_code')
    ->get();   

// El with hace que se adjunten variables al view.
return view('admin.posts.create')->with('estados', $estados)->with('cpostales', $cpostales);
}
```

Comment: I would completely rethink what it is you are trying to accomplish.  There is never a reason to load that many items into a select box.  I would use some ajax and have them select through categories that narrows the results into smaller chunks of data.

Comment: Yeah, I know, though, could you guide me on that? Novice here. Any tutorial or something would be appreciated, involving Laravel of course.

Comment: Google these keywords: dynamic populating javascript ajax jquery.

Answer (score 2):

One option if you don't mind using jQuery UI is to use [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) with a text field, instead of a drop-down. Here's some working code I used.

**In your controller, create a function that returns a small number of postal codes:**

```php
<?php

use Response;

...


public function searchPostalCode(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->input('term');

    $results = [];

    $queries = DB::table('db_postalcodes')
    ->where('postal_code', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')  //search 'postal_code' column
    ->take(5)->get();                              // get 5 results

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name];
    }

    return Response::json($results);
}
```

**Define a route for it, in Laravel's web routes**

```php
Route::get('/searchPostalCode', 'PostalCodeController@searchPostalCode');
```

**Then, in your blade template, add this Snippet**

```
<input id="postal-code" type="text" name="postal-code">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
    $( "#postal-code" ).autocomplete({
          source: "{{URL('/searchPostalCode')}}",
          minLength: 3,
          select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#postal-code').val(ui.item.value);
          }
        });
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I'm implementing your code now, but I'm getting a `GET http://apr2.test/buscarCodigoPostal?term=200 404 (Not Found)` error. I'm looking at it, but maybe you know already what's happening ?¿

Comment: I wrote it outside of a `::group` I had, but now I'm getting a `GET http://apr2.test/searchPostalCode?term=200 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Any idea what could it be?

Comment: @dawn hmm. not sure. Also make sure you include "Response" at the top of the controller by adding `use Response;` after `use DB;` etc. Will update my answer.

Comment: take a view at my code please, maybe you'll find some text wrong (ids) but I don't get the 500 error: https://ghostbin.com/paste/hv85z

Comment: Please check: In the controller you should use `$term = $request->input('term');` instead of 'postalcode'. In your input element, you should use lowercase ID `#postal-code` (Now you have both #postalCode and #postal-code